# How to Use Group By clause when we use Aggregate function in the Joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to join three tables and to calculate the Sum(Quantity) of the Table A.
I tried something and I get the desired output. But still I have confusion based on aggregate function and Group By clause.

While calculating the sum value by joining two or more tables, what are the columns we need to mention in the Group By clause and why do we need to give those columns?

For Example: Here is my table and the desired query.

```
TableA: ItemID, JobOrderID, CustomerID, DivisionID, Quantity
TableB: ItemID, ItemName, SpecificationID
TableC: SpecificationID, SpecificationName
TableD: DivisionID, DivisionName
TableE: JobOrderID, JobOrderNo.
TableF: CustomerID, CustomerName
```

I want to get the Sum(Quantity) based on `ItemID`, `CustomerID`, `JobOrderID` and `DivisionID`.

I wrote the following query and it's working fine. But if I remove any column in the Group By clause, it doesn't give the desired result. Why? What does the Group By clause do here? How to specify the Group By clause when using Aggregate function? Here is my Query.

```
    SELECT 
            B.ItemName + ' - ' + C.SpecificationName AS 'ItemName',
            SUM(A.Quantity) AS 'Quantity',
            A.ItemID,
            D.DivisionName,
            F.CustomerName,
            E.JobOrderNo,
            A.DivisionID,
            A.JobOrderID,
            A.CustomerID

    FROM
            TableA A  
            INNER JOIN TableB B ON B.ItemID = A.ItemID 
            INNER JOIN TableC C ON C.SpecificationID = B.SpecificationID
            INNER JOIN TableD D ON D.DivisionID = A.DivisionID
            LEFT JOIN TableE E ON E.JobOrderID = A.JobOrderID
            LEFT JOIN TableF F ON F.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
    WHERE
            A.ItemID = @ItemID
    GROUP BY
            A.ItemID,
            A.JobOrderID,
            A.DivisionID,
            A.CustomerID,
            D.DivisionName,
            F.CustomerName,
            E.JobOrderNo,
            B.ItemName,
            C.SpecificationName
```

Any one please give suggestion about the Group By Clause by considering this as an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GROUP BY` for any unique combination of the specified columns does aggregation (like sum, min etc). If you don't specify some column name in the `GROUP BY` clause or in the aggregate function its unknown to the SQL engine which value it should return for that kind of column.

Comment: So if we select some columns means, we need to give those columns in the Group By clause too. Is it so?

Comment: Yes, selected column must be in `group by` or in agreagtion like: `select max(column_name)`

Answer (score 6):

[GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) groups a selected set of rows into a set of summary rows by the values of one or more columns or expressions in SQL Server 2008 R2. One row is returned for each group. Aggregate functions in the SELECT clause  list provide information about each group instead of individual rows.

```
SELECT a.City, COUNT(bea.AddressID) AS EmployeeCount
FROM Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea 
    INNER JOIN Person.Address AS a
        ON bea.AddressID = a.AddressID
GROUP BY a.City
```

> The GROUP BY clause has an
>   ISO-compliant syntax and a
>   non-ISO-compliant syntax. Only one
>   syntax style can be used in a single
>   SELECT statement. Use the ISO
>   compliant syntax for all new work. The
>   non-ISO compliant syntax is provided
>   for backward compatibility.

In *ISO-compliant* syntax each table or view column in any nonaggregate expression in the  list must be included in the `GROUP BY` list.

```
select pub_id, type, avg(price), sum(total_sales)
from titles
group by pub_id, type
```

Refering to [Organizing query results into groups: the group by clause](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/8499;pt=8007)

> *Sybase* or *non-ISO-compliant* syntax lifts restrictions on what you can
>   include or omit in the `select` list
>   of a query that includes `group by`:
>
> - The columns in the select list are not limited to the grouping columns
>     and columns used with the vector
>     aggregates.
> - The columns specified by group by are not limited to those non-aggregate
>     columns in the select list.

Example:

```
select type, title_id, avg(price), avg(advance) 
from titles 
group by type
```

Comment: So if we select some columns means, we need to give those columns in the Group By clause too. Is it so?

Comment: this makes a lot more sense, group by only show a reprensentative row for the group therefore all the non aggregate fields should be included into the group by clause.

Answer (score 3):

To use aggregate functions like sum without group by, use the over clause.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #a (ida int, name varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE #b  (ida int, number int)

INSERT INTO #a VALUES(1,'one')
INSERT INTO #a VALUES(2,'two')

INSERT INTO #b VALUES(1,2)
INSERT INTO #b VALUES(1,3)
INSERT INTO #b VALUES(2,1)

SELECT DISTINCT a.ida, sum(number) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ida) FROM #a a
INNER JOIN #b b on a.ida = b.ida
```