# grouping while querying oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Below is the query that i am using. but

> Query:

```
SELECT   c.session_id     session_number, 
         u.first_name     first_name, 
         u.last_name      last_name, 
         Min(c.timestamp) session_start_ts, 
         Max(c.timestamp) session_end_ts, 
         Count( 
         CASE 
                  WHEN c.message_type='IN' THEN 1 
                  ELSE NULL 
         END)                  message_in_count, 
         Count(c.message_type) total_messages 
FROM     users u 
join     chatlog c 
ON       u.user_id = c.user_id 
WHERE    Trunc(c.timestamp) BETWEEN To_date('2017-10-11','YYYY-MM-DD') AND      To_date('2017-11-09','YYYY-MM-DD') 
GROUP BY c.session_id, 
order by timestamp;
```

The problem is that it gives an error stating "not a GROUP BY expression". But instead of just grouping by session id  if i use :

```
 group by c.session_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, c.timestamp
```

It works though the values of first_name and last_name are same for a particulat session_id and timestamp also i am only taking the max. so cant understand why i am unable to group by session_id only.

Comment: You can try this `group by  session_number,  first_name,  last_name` It will work. if it is not work than post your error message.

Comment: @NikuNjRathod it would be similar to what i mentioned that by adding last_name and first_name in group by. the query is working. but i just want to group it by session_id only. and secondly using just session_number instead of c.session_id it gives error stating :" "SESSION_NUMBER": invalid identifier"

Comment: Please visit this link for your solution URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424092/how-to-use-group-by-clause-when-we-use-aggregate-function-in-the-joins

Answer (score 1):

> "cant understand why i am unable to group by session_id only"

The rule of Oracle aggregation functions is that we need to group by **all** the non-aggregated columns in the projection. In your case that is

```
group by c.session_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
```

---

> " how do we overcome that. i mean there must be a way that you can overcome that. so that if you want to select multiple columns and just group by a particular column?"

This doesn't apply in your case. You say:

> "the values of first_name and last_name are same for a particulat (sic) session_id"

which means grouping by `session_id,first_name,last_name` is the same as grouping by `session_id` alone. But as a general point, we can use analytical functions to aggregate values in a different window from the result set. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004).

Comment: so how do we overcome that. i mean there must be a way that you can overcome that. so that if you want to select multiple columns and just group by a particular column?